# Continuity and differentiability of $[x\sin\pi x]$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

How to successfully analyse the continuity and differentiability of $[x\sin\pi x]$ in the interval $-1$ to $1$. My concepts of continuity and differentiability are clear but when it comes to these type of tricky functions specially in the greatest integer, I get confused. If anybody can help, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: plot the function on (x,y) plane, you can find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if I have to plot it, then why would I ask on this platform. That, I already know.

Comment: You can compute some special points to find the rules. For example, the values at -1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1.